# How can I fit a function to another function?

Tags: fitting

I want to fit the gaussian function to power law function from the end of gaussian fitting curve to the peak of it,

```
ample = -1.05296;
x0 = -0.992208;
sigma = -0.513743;

ample*(1/(sigma*Sqrt[2*Pi]))*Exp[-(1/2)*(((x - x0)/sigma)^(2))]

FindFit[ample*(1/(sigma*Sqrt[2*Pi]))*
Exp[-(1/2)*(((x - x0)/sigma)^(2))], {a*(-x)^n, {a, n}, -3 <= 
x <= -1}, {a, n}, x];
```

How can i deal with it?

Comment: As an experiment you might try creating a `Table` of enough `{x,y}` points from your power law function, use `Fit` on those points with your gaussian as usual and then `Plot` both the power law and gaussian on the same graph to see if this is acceptable. Different experiment, `Integrate[(power-gaussian)^2]` over a suitable domain and see if you can `Minimize` that to get an acceptable solution. Can you see how and why you might do each of those?

Comment: Is `Series[ ample*(... etc etc...), {x, -2, 2}]` good enough?  It produces a second-order polynomial approximation of your function around x=-2.

Comment: Thanks Bill and evanb, i`ll try!